# How to directly perform arithmetic operation on user input?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

If a user passes two values,I want to directly compute the subtraction of the two values and store it in a variable.Something like

A user passes 4 and 3.So I will directly compute the result using list comprehension and store it in a variable.

So instead of doing this

```
num1,num2 = input().split(" ")
num = int(num1)-int(num2)
print(num)
```

I want to compute the entire thing in a list comprehension.So far what I have tried

```
num = [j[0]-j[1] for j in [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]]
```

But it gives error.How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num = [i[0] - i[1] for i in [list(map(int, input().split(" ")))]]
```

or

```
num = [int(i1) - int(i2) for i1, i2 in [input().split(" ")]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!This is what I needed.